# How does one query a user's AD group recursively using libwbclient

Tags: active-directory, samba

I am trying to query from winbindd all the AD groups a user is in.

I've tried using wbcLookupSids() to look up the user's Group Sids.

However when using wbcLookupSids() on the groups that the user is a member of, I only get the group's own Sid.

Do I HAVE to use LDAP to recursively find my user's groups?

Answer (score 0):

wbinfo does the same. Following is the source -

https://github.com/encukou/samba/blob/master/nsswitch/wbinfo.c

You may want to check these wbinfo options -

-r |--user-groups username   # will have to be an SA account belonging to an Admin group in AD

-i |--user-info user         # user info

--group-info group           # Info about a group

--gid-info gid               # Get group info from gid.

PS: use a synced admin AD account to extract best info from these commands

Hope this helps. All the best!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).